# Plone 4: Customize News Item as folder

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

How can I customize News Item content type to behave like a folder (accept files, folders as children)?

`/portal_types/News%20Item/manage_propertiesForm`

Changing Allowed content types seems to have no effect.

Comment: You generally will have better luck asking questions in https://community.plone.org

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try searching for collective.folderishtypes, that provides "Folderish News Item". Then look for 'folderish' at http://docs.plone.org for further reading. At this moment, using Dexterity to customize content types is better for future upgrades.